# How can I send many(10) requestify, sync in nodejs?

Tags: arrays, node.js, request, npm

I am developing nodejs application

I have array with 10 URL

```
var urlArray = [{url01},{url02},{url03},......,{url10}];
var arrayLength = 10;
var reqData = {message:'Wel Come'};

for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength ; i ++ ){ 
requestify.post(urlArray[i],reqData)
    .then(function(resonse){
         console.log(response);
    },function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
    }
```

I need to send 10 requestify sync way

Answer (score 2):

You can do it following way.

```
var i = 0;
var urlArray = [{url01},{url02},{url03},......,{url10}];

var makeCall = function(x){
   if( x < urlArray.length ) {
       requestify.post(urlArray[i],reqData)
          .then(function(resonse){
              makeCall(x+1);
          },function(err){
              console.log(err);
       });
   }
}; 
makeCall(0);
```